# which event will be fired when a particular row is clicked in datagridview?

Tags: events, c#-4.0, datagridview, windows

I am having a windows application where I have a gridview on one of my form. I want to fire an event when a particular row header is clicked.So which event will be fired??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick.aspx
I think this is what you are looking for.

```
void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick( object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e){

    if(e.RowIndex == Whatever row you want){
      [Do something]
      }

 }
```

I am not sure there is a way to do exactly what you want, but this should be a simple workaround.

Comment: Tim I have tried with the same event. This event is fired whenever you click any row header but I want an event which gets fired when a particular row header is clicked.